# Probability picking from n keys question

Tags: probability

> **A shopkeeper has $n$ keys in his pocket out of which only one opens the door of his shop. He tries the keys one by one, at random. For a
>   fixed $k ∈ {1, 2, . . . , n}$, compute the probability that he will
>   open the door at the $k th$ attempt if he discards the keys that do
>   not open the door.**

I dont understand why the answer isnt $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)}{n^k}$. It makes sense for this question and usually the answer is what I wrote. Instead its given as $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Before you start, each key is equally likely to open the door.  So each key has a $1/n$ chance.

Comment: But he discards the keys so once they dont work we cant count them in

Comment: You are answering the question from the viewpoint of not having used any keys, not after using $k-1$ keys.

Answer (score 2):

For the $1st$ trial, clearly $P(X) = \frac{1}{n}$

For the $2nd$ trial, the probability is $\frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{n-1}$ as there are $n-1$ wrong keys for the first trial and then there are only $n-1$ keys left to pick the correct one from the second.

Similarly for the $kth$ trial, the probability is $$\frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n-k}{n-k+1} \cdot \frac{1}{n-k}$$ and so by telescopic cancellation, the answer is the probability is $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability is
$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}P(X>1)$$
then
\begin{align}
P(X>1)&=\frac1{n-1}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}P(X>2)\\
&=\frac1{n-1}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}\left(\frac1{n-2}+\frac{n-3}{n-2}P(X>3)\right)\\
\end{align}
and so on until you hit $k$ trials.

---

Your answer is based on
$$\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{\underbrace{n}_{\text{should be }(n-1)}}\cdot\frac{n-3}{\underbrace{n}_{\text{should be } (n-2) }}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n-k+1}{\underbrace{n}_{\text{should be }(n-k+2)}}$$
which didn't take into account of the throwing keys away part.

Comment: I dont understand why my answer is wrong though

Comment: @NoteBook pls see the part below the line

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the first key opens the door is $1/n.$

The probability that the second key opens the door is the probability that the first doesn't open the door, times the probability that the second key does, or $$\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}$$

Continue in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the first key you try isn't the right key is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. The probability that the second key isn't the right key either is $\frac{n-2}{n-1}$ since there's $n-1$ keys left.

Using the same logic, the probability that you open the door at the $k$th attempt is 
$$\frac{(n-1)\cdot(n-2) \cdot ... \cdot (n-k)}{n \cdot (n-1) \cdot ... \cdot (n-k+1)} \frac {1}{n-k}= \frac{1}{n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the shoekeeper stops at the right key the sequence of trials should stop at k, neverthless, the shoekeeper continues to $n$.

- Sum of all combinations of keys is equal to:

$$1+\binom{1}{n-1}+\binom{2}{n-1}2!+\binom{3}{n-1}3!+...+\binom{n-1}{n-1}(n-1)!$$

- The probability is:

$$P(k)=\frac{\binom{k-1}{n-1}(k-1)!}{1+\binom{1}{n-1}+\binom{2}{n-1}2!+\binom{3}{n-1}3!+...+\binom{n-1}{n-1}(n-1)!}$$